# tvOS: How to move TabView button off to the side

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos

I have an existing app with a `TabView` as its main interface. For example:

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            RecentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("One")
                }
            RecentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Two")
                }
            RecentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Three")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now they want to add a tab item but have it off in the top right corner like this:

[image]

How is this possible to do?

Comment: Make it a button instead, and programmatically trigger it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that and was able to add a button as a subview. But, I'm not clear how to change the main view once that button is focused. But I'm really new to SwiftUI so I'll keep playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but this is the general idea. The key is to `.tag()` your views so you can refer to them with a `@State var`. Then it doesn't matter what you use to trigger the change. It can be user initiated or programmed.

```
struct TabViewSideButton: View {
    
    // This trackes what view to show.
    @State private var tabSelection = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
                RecentView(text: "One")
                    .tag(1) // tags go on each view.
                RecentView(text: "Two")
                    .tag(2)
                RecentView(text: "Three")
                    .tag(3)
            }
            HStack {
                // Set your variable whereever
                Picker("", selection: $tabSelection) {
                    ForEach([1,2], id: \.self) { choice in
                        Text(spellout.string(from: choice as NSNumber) ?? "")
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                
            }
            .frame(width: 200)
            .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    // Set your variable whereever
                    tabSelection = 3
                } label: {
                    Text("Three")
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
    }
    
    var spellout: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this shows how to change to a certain tab from a source outside the TabView. But what I'm after is to have a button OUTSIDE the TabView yet behaves exactly like one of the TabView's children (i.e. triggers when focused and changes the main view)

Comment: I have no idea what this means: "button OUTSIDE the TabView yet behaves exactly like one of the TabView's children (i.e. triggers when focused and changes the main view)". A button triggers on tap... there is no focus. I put the picker outside of the tabview as well as it will reserve space for a TabItem at the bottom, regardless of where the item exists or not, at least on iOS. YMMV on MacOS, but if it doesn't reserve a spot, you just need to place the TabItems you want on the subviews. However, the code I showed is the way Apple suggests for programatic tab switching.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that this is for tvOS so focus is important. So when focus moves to tab One, the main content area changes to screen One, tab Two -> screen Two, etc. A button/tab off to the side that behaves just like a tab. So in the screenshot in the OP, a "Four" button off to the side that looks like the other tabs and changes to screen Four when focused.

Comment: Well, the selection keys off of the `tabSelection` variable, so you can change the button UI with that, simply by `tabSelection == 3`. You can have the button do whatever you want at that point, UI wise.